# Убрать <p> в контентной части на уровне темы Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Сегодня у меня возникла задача удалить атоматическое добавление `<p></p>`  в шаблоне wordpress.
Я нашел следующий способ.

http://webgyry.info/lishnie-elementyi-p-i-br-v-wordpress-kak-ubrat/

```
//TODO:<p> tag for client
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

Как занести данное действие на уровень шаблона Wordpress?
Основная цель удаление `<p></p>` вокруг ссылок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте следующую строку в файл `function.php` вашей темы:

```
remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

Если нужно отключить функцию `wpautop` и для цитат, то добавьте и эту строку:

```
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```